# 'relevel' function not working to reset the reference level in a linear model

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm, levels

I’m applying a simple linear model with a 3 levels treatment factor ("no", "one", "three")

> model<-lm(response variable~treatment, data)

I obtain the following summary:

```
                    Estimate    Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)         41.163      3.715       11.082  1.82e-13 *** 
treatment one       11.731      5.158       2.274   0.0287 *   
treatment three     5.315       5.158       1.030   0.3094
```

in which, obviously, the reference level (in alphabetical order) is "no".

Now I want to change the reference level from "no" to "one" and I apply:

```
data$treatment <- relevel(data$treatment, ref="one")
```

It seems to work because if I ask to see the level sequence

```
levels(data$treatment)
```

I know get:

> [1] "one"   "no"    "three"

However, if I know run again the model with this new reference level I get exactly the same summary and the reference level is still the first “no”

```
                   Estimate     Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)         41.163      3.715       11.082  1.82e-13 *** 
treatment one       11.731      5.158       2.274   0.0287 *   
treatment three     5.315       5.158       1.030   0.3094
```

Of course I know I could manually modify the levels' name to change their alphabetical order in a way that my level "one" becomes the first in alphabetical order and so will be used as reference.
But I would anyway be interested to understand why the "relevel" function I am applying is not working.
Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Hi L.Loc, you did it correctly, unless there's something else. can you do dput(data) ?

Comment: Agree - and in addition to showing your data, also can you edit your question with your `lm` statement exactly as used?

Comment: I got it, I was not recalling the data set name (data=dataset name) in the lm statement. Now it works. Thanks @Ben for your suggestion to get a look at this